# Object is instantiated with its own rotation that I cant change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity project, I am trying to instantiate an orb that moves forward when the player clicks.
When the orb is instantiated, it always goes the same direction, no matter which way the player is facing.
I have tried my hand at getting it to go the same direction as the player, to no avail.

How do I instantiate an object with the same rotation as my player?

The instantiating code:

```
            if (polyWand.activeSelf == true)
    {
        Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.x, player.transform.rotation.y, player.transform.rotation.z);
        Instantiate(fireSpellPrefab, SpellLocation, playerRotation);
    }
```

The behaviour of the insantiated object:

```
void Update ()
{
    Destroy(this, 5f);
    transform.rotation = Player.transform.rotation;
    transform.position += Vector3.forward * 9 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is always sending an object along the Z axis because transform.position doesn't know which direction the object's facing. It's an entirely different Vector3 to the rotation vector. To get something to move in a direction relative to the object's rotation, try:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * 9 * Time.deltaTime;
```

I haven't tried this but each transform has its own forward Vector. And as transform contains both rotation and position vectors, this should work.

But typically for something like this you'd use transform.forward to help with the initial positioning of an object and then use Rigidbody.velocity to actually get it moving.

Edit:

I've tried something similar and transform.forward itself will provide the starting point for your projectile and the direction of travel. I've created an example for you.

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float projectileSpeed;
    public Transform projectile;

    private Transform instantiatedProjectile;

    private bool projectileLaunched;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var rotationAngle = 0f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rotationAngle = -speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAngle);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rotationAngle = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAngle);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, transform.forward, Quaternion.identity);
            projectileLaunched = true;
        }

        if (projectileLaunched)
        {
            var projPos = instantiatedProjectile.position;
            projPos += transform.forward * projectileSpeed;
            instantiatedProjectile.position = projPos;
        }
    }
}
```

For this example, all I did was create a cube as the player, created a ball as the projectile and made it into a prefab. Then I attached this script to the player cube.

Comment: I've written an example for you.

Comment: Just looked at your code again and I think I see what you might have done. Transform.forward has to be in the class instantiating the projectile. Or you could use transform.position += Player.transform.forward * 9 * Time.DeltaTime in the projectile class.